# How can i draw inner radius in css?

Tags: html, css

Please help me out i want to make a div like this[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: i tried with border radius but that draws the other way.

Comment: Please show us your code even if it not works, We will try to help you in fixing your problem.

Comment: You could place another div (with border-radius) in the bottom right corner of your main div with `background-color` set to white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method # 01:**

Use [`raidal-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient):

```css
body {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
}
.box {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, transparent 60px, #000 60px);
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

**Method # 02:**

You can create it with combination of `:before` or `:after` pseudo element and  `box-shadow` css property.

```css
body {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
}

.box:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  height: 100px;
  right: -35px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest method will be using a `pseudo element`. By absolutely positioning the `:after` element, you can get the desired effect.

```css
.box {
  background: #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  right: -75px;
  bottom: -75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: but if i dont want white background at the rounded side then how?

Comment: this is done well but when i set image inside this div it doesn't cut from that edge.

Answer (score 2):

Try this CSS,

```
.rec{
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    width:600px;
}

.rec:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px; right: -20px;
    border-bottom: 100px solid white;
    border-left: 100px solid white;
    width: 0;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:150px;

}
```